# django url get method urlpatterns

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://chinafhp.sinaapp.com/search/?q=ag

urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'web.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^web/', include('web.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:

    url(r'^serach/$',views.serach),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$',views.home),

    url(r'^movie/([^/]+)/$',views.movieList),
    url(r'^tv/([^/]+)/$',views.tvList),
)
```

why?

Comment: maybe because you spelled it wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`url(r'^serach/$',views.serach),`

should be

`url(r'^search/$',views.search),`

Answer (score 1):

Seems you misspelled **search** word there, But the thing is you entered `views.serach` correctly, because django didn't complain about it so there is a `serach` view definitively.

So if you want to access you url you will be fine by:

```
http://chinafhp.sinaapp.com/serach/?q=ag
```

Comment: actually, http://chinafhp.sinaapp.com/search/?q=ag seems to be fine now